# Handling batches of data points with common target in forecasting problem

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a time-series forecasting problem at hand.

My data is such that multiple events occur at every time-step, and exhibit onto-mapping with the target column. The current representation has a unique row for each event regardless of its time-step. However, in this representation, there is no clear indication that all events at one time-step map to the same target value. This is further complicated by the fact that these events have one categorical attribute.

Note that my data is such that a category can have at most one event in a specific time-step. Also note that an event is denoted by the tuple $(attribute\_1, attribute\_2, category, timestep)$

An example would be -

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{attribute 1} & \text{attribute 2} & \text{category} & \text{timestep} & \text{target} \\ \hline
& a1 & b1 & c1 & T1 & output\_1 \\ \hline
& a2 & b2 & c2 & T1 & output\_1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Passing training data in this form would presumably be sub-optimal.

Is there a better way of representation?

I was thinking of dropping the category and collecting the event data per timestep along with one-hot categorical columns as -

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{events} & \text{timestep} & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & \text{target} \\ \hline
& [[a1, b1], [a2, b2]] & T1 & 1 & 1 & output\_1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Here, I have to trust that my model will pick up on which categories were present and what they are at every time-step. But is there an alternate, more efficient, representation?

Comment: Can you give an example of how your data is structured? I find it hard to understand your explanation.